# The cone is not a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am not very familiar to differentiable manifolds, so I would appreciate some hints or reasonings about why the cone
$$ M = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2-z^2 = 0, z\geq0\} $$
is not a regular submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.

Also, is it possible to give $M$ structure of differentiable manifold of dim. 2 with the usual topology of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Hint: Look at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @Moya i'm including only those points with $z\geq 0$, so it is a manifold, but not smooth.

Comment: @Moya I clearly know that $(0,0,0)$ is the problem, but don't know what is clearly a regular submanifold.

Comment: Okay, sorry again. I'll write something up.

Comment: What is your definition of regular submanifolds?

Answer (score 0):

If M is a submanifold and p is a point of V, the set of all first derivatives of all curves through p is a vector subspaces of the ambient space.

If you do not know this, then you should prove it.

Once you have it, show that this does not hold for the apex of the cone