# Show that the upper cone is a smooth manifold but is not a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

**I would like to know if my solution to the following exercise is correct**

> Let $C$ be the upper cone:
> $$C=\big\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2=z^2,\, z\geq 0\big\}$$
> (a) Prove that $C$ is a smooth manifold.
>
> (b) Prove that $C$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.

For (a) we follow the [Nigel Hitchin's](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/files/LectureNotes/Differentiable_manifolds/manifolds2014.pdf) definition 5 of smooth manifold. Since the map:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\varphi:&C&\longrightarrow & \mathbb R^2\\
&(x,y,z)&\longmapsto &(x,y)
\end{array}$$
is a bijection, the pair $(C,\varphi)$ is a (global) chart of $C$. In fact, $\varphi$ is an homeomorphism so $C$ must be Hausdorff and has a countable basis of open sets. This implies that $\mathcal A=\{(C,\varphi)\}$ is an atlas of $C$ and $C$ is a smooth manifold.

For (b) we follow the definition 12 of submanifolds. Suppose that the natural inclusion $i:C\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is smooth and consider $\alpha:(-\xi,\xi)\to C$ a smooth map in $C$ such that $\alpha(0)=(0,0,0)$. By hipothesis, the composition $i\circ\alpha$ must be a smooth path in $\mathbb R^3$. However the $z$-component of this map is defined by:
$$z:t\mapsto \sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}$$
where $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ are the $x$-component and $y$-component of $\alpha$ respectively. It is clear that $z=z(t)$ is not smooth at $t=0$. Thus $i\circ\alpha$ cannot be smooth on its domain. This implies that $C$ cannot be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of *upper cone*? The equation you've written down certainly does NOT define a manifold by any definition. Nor is $\varphi$ a bijection. I suspect you mean $z\ge 0$ in the definition.

Comment: For some $\alpha$, $\sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}$ is actually smooth. For example $\alpha (t) = (t^2, 0, t^2)$.

Comment: This is asked several times on MSE: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966187/showing-that-the-cone-x2-y2-z2-0-x-geq-0-is-not-an-embedded-submanifold), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573019/in-what-context-would-one-think-a-cone-surface-is-not-a-smooth-manifold), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728582/proving-that-the-cone-is-not-a-smooth-manifold), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527938/the-cone-is-not-a-regular-submanifold-of-mathbbr3).

Comment: @ArcticChar - If the OP had asked for a solution, then indeed, it would have been asked many times before. But instead the OP asked for a validation of *their* solution, which is a different question.

Comment: Rather than considering an arbitrary curve $\alpha$, it is sufficient to define a specific curve and show that $i\circ \alpha$ is not smooth. In particular, $\alpha : t \mapsto (t,0)$.

Comment: Many thanks for all anwers! I will take $\alpha: t\mapsto (t,0)$ in order to finish my proof!